# Sort dates before today in ascending order and after today in descending order

Tags: php, arrays, date, sorting

I have the following array

```
$array = [
    '2022-06-30', 
    '2022-04-20', 
    '2021-04-07',
    '2022-09-09', 
    '2022-03-08',
    '2021-08-07', 
    '2022-10-12'
];
```

and I want to sort every date in the past ASC
and every date in the future DESC.

How can I do this?

With "today" being `2022-06-02`, my expected result:

```
array (
  0 => '2021-04-07',  // before today, ASC
  1 => '2021-08-07',  // before today, ASC
  2 => '2022-03-08',  // before today, ASC
  3 => '2022-04-20',  // before today, ASC
  4 => '2022-10-12',  // after today, DESC
  5 => '2022-09-09',  // after today, DESC
  6 => '2022-06-30',  // after today, DESC
)
```

Comment: Please can you [edit] to include the desired output for that input? Remember to also include what you're using as "today", so that the question carries on making sense if someone reads it in the future.

Comment: @Erik your question does not clarify how the sorting algorithm should treat an input date that is equal to today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a job for [usort()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) with a comparison function you provide.

Your comparison function gets called like `cmp($a, $b)`. $a and $b are two items from your array. If $a goes before $b in the output, you return -1. If $a goes after $b, return 1. If they're the same return 0. So, you'll need a comparision function implementing your specific before / after logic.

The `usort()` function calls your comparison function whenever it needs to compare one date with another to do your sort. It calls your function **O(n log(n))** times with different pairs of values.

Something like this? NOT, repeat NOT, debugged.

```php
$nowTimeForMySort = time();

function cmpDates ($a, $b) {
    global $nowTimeForMySort;
    /* equal times, return 0 */
    if ($a == $b) return 0;

    $aTime = strtotime($a);
    $bTime = strtotime($b);

    /* if one date is in the past and the other in the future,
     * always put the date in the past before the date in the future. */
    if ($aTime <= $nowTimeForMySort && $bTime  > $nowTimeForMySort) return -1;
    if ($aTime >  $nowTimeForMySort && $bTime <= $nowTimeForMySort) return 1;

    /* when we get here, both dates are either past or future. */
    if ($aTime <= $nowTimeForMySort) {
       /* past dates: ascending */
       if ($aTime < $bTime) return -1;
       if ($aTime > $bTime) return 1;
    } else {
       /* future dates: descending */
       if ($aTime < $bTime) return 1; 
       if ($aTime > $bTime) return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Then use that function in `usort()` like this.

```php
usort($a, 'cmpDates');
```

**Pro tip**: You must be absolutely sure that your comparison function's output depends only, deterministically, on its two inputs and not on anything that might change. That's why this example stuffs the current time into a global variable: we don't want the time to change while the sort is in progress or the results might be very strange.

**Pro tip** Some languages' comparison functions allow the return of negative / zero / positive numbers. php's requires you to return -1, 0, 1.

Comment: There are ways to shorten this comparison function. Written this way, though, it spells out the logic in detail. These things are difficult to debug, so code we can reason about is helpful.

Comment: I agree with your comment but it also motivates devs to not learn anything new in the language in the name of simplicity.

Comment: Your second "pro tip" is incorrect. PHP requires only that the comparison function returns an integer, so `return -2;` is just fine (but `return -0.5;` will be interpreted as equivalent to `return 0;`).

Comment: Once you boil down the plain English requirements, it becomes obvious that ASC sorting only needs to be reversed when both dates are greater than today.  This clarified perspective eliminates the need for excessive nested conditionals, inline comments, and multiple returns.  Furthermore, datetime functions are not required nor is the use of `global`.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting use-case. For this, after the custom sort, the first portion will have past dates in ascending order and second portion of the array will have present/future dates in decreasing order. For this, you can use [`usort`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) as below:

- If the 2 dates are present/future dates, compare and return the values safely with greater date coming first than the smaller date.
- If the 2 dates doesn't satisfy the above step, compare them as is and return the values.

**Snippet:**

```
<?php

$today_dt = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', date("Y-m-d") . " 00:00:00");

usort($array, function($a, $b) use ($today_dt){
    $d1 =  DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $a . " 00:00:00");
    $d2 =  DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $b . " 00:00:00");
    
    if($d1 >= $today_dt && $d2 >= $today_dt){
        return $d2 <=> $d1; // DESC
    }
    
    return $d1 <=> $d2; // ASC
});
```

[**Online Demo**](https://onlinephp.io/c/4d6d6)

**Update:**

As mentioned by @IMSoP in the comments, you can make the code more concise without having to manually attach the midnight time string. [`More info`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php)

```
<?php

$array = ['2022-09-09', '2022-06-30', '2022-04-20', '2021-04-07', '2022-03-08', '2021-08-07', '2022-10-12'];

$today_dt = new DateTime('today midnight');

usort($array, function($a, $b) use ($today_dt){
    $d1 =  DateTime::createFromFormat('!Y-m-d', $a);
    $d2 =  DateTime::createFromFormat('!Y-m-d', $b);
    if($d1 >= $today_dt && $d2 >= $today_dt){
        return $d2 <=> $d1; // DESC
    }
    return $d1 <=> $d2; // ASC
});

print_r($array);
```

[**Online Demo**](https://onlinephp.io/c/bcb52)

Comment: Rather than `date()` with `DateTime`, you can use `$today_dt = new DateTime('today midnight');` And instead of adding `" 00:00:00"` to the dates, you can use a format of `'Y-m-d|'` or `'!Y-m-d'` as the format, to reset the time fields to midnight, rather than "now".

Comment: @IMSoP I appreciate your suggestion. I learnt something new. I will update my answer in the morning :)

Answer (score 1):

Your logic requires that sorting DESC should only occur when both dates are greater than today.  Inside the custom callback of `usort()` use a ternary condition to deliver the correct multiplier to adjust the sorting direction.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/GNZHh))

```
$array = [
    '2022-06-30', 
    '2022-04-20', 
    '2021-04-07',
    '2022-09-09', 
    '2022-03-08',
    '2021-08-07', 
    '2022-10-12'
];

$today = '2022-06-02'; // date('Y-m-d');

usort($array, fn($a, $b) => ($a > $today && $b > $today ? -1 : 1) * ($a <=> $b));
var_export($array);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => '2021-04-07',
  1 => '2021-08-07',
  2 => '2022-03-08',
  3 => '2022-04-20',
  4 => '2022-10-12',
  5 => '2022-09-09',
  6 => '2022-06-30',
)
```

---

A more concise, but less efficient approach could look like this: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/Wb3CJ))

```
usort($array, fn($a, $b) => (min($a, $b) > $today ? -1 : 1) * ($a <=> $b));
```

Comment: nice, still banging my head to imagine a real world use case for OP's requirements in the 1st place...

Comment: I agree.  It's a rather odd sorting algorithm.